# Release of a UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, memory-leaks

I made a UIView animation using a 150 .PNG images sequence loaded in a NSMutableArray called `sequenceArray`, hosted in UIImageView subclass. My problem is that after the animation sequence has been played, the memory is still occupied by this extra 450MB (3MBx150 frames)  and I can't release it.  I tried adding `[animationView removeFromSuperView];` on completion block but, as I imagined, it didn't work, because animation didn't appear, and also I tried `[sequenceArray removeAllObjects];` without any success. 
I'm not sure if a `__weak` reference could help me or a manual release without ARC.
Have you any suggestions? Thank you!

Here the animation method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     animationView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
                     [self addSubview:animationView];
                     animationView.animationImages = sequenceArray;
                     animationView.animationDuration = animationDuration;
                     animationView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
                     [animationView startAnimating];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
```

Comment: Maybe try and alloc/init the animationView outside the animationBlock as it has a reference of it within that (setting it to __block or __weak would help with that), and just animate the alpha in.

Comment: Why are you even using block animation in this case?

Comment: I second what @Unheilig said. It's unnecessary to animate in an animating object. Also why are you loading so many high quality images? Maybe think about running them through Imageoptim.

Comment: You are right. I was doing all stuff in a unnecessary animating object. I also set Compress PNG Files as "NO" and it's a bit better. I tried to keep local `animationView` as a __block variable but it is retained and so a memory problem is still there.